Read-only Permissions page
Is there a way to set the permissions page read-only? I want to prevent certain roles from making any changes to the permissions but still able to view the permissions page. Alternatively, if that is not possible, perhaps prevent roles from saving the permissions page.

Does this answer your question? Separate permissions for form access and form submit Current answers are from Drupal 7 however.

There is also this module that could be a good start point: https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_ui_readonly

To accomplish this I would write a hook_form_alter() to disable all the inputs depending on the role of the current user
